# Update a cell to the title of inserted object - Excel-VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an inserted shape that I want used as a button. I have almost 400 of these named inserted obects actually. My question is, how do I use a macro to set a cell, cell E10 in this case, to equal the label(title) of the object. All object titles are numbers.

Worded diffrently, I want to asign the same macro to every object so that clicking the object will set cell E10 to equal the visable title of the object.

I found numerous examples of changing the title of an object or button to match another cell, but could not find this type of question answered. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign this macro (in a standard module) to all shapes:

```
Sub ShowName()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E10").Value = Application.Caller
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**

This will place both the name of the shape and its displayed text in the cell:

```
Sub ShowNameAndText()
    Dim s As Shape, t As String
    t = Application.Caller
    msg = t & vbCrLf & ActiveSheet.Shapes(t).TextFrame.Characters.Text
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E10").Value = msg
End Sub
```

Comment: When I insert an object it seems to asign it a "name box" name, for example "Rounded Rectangle 54". I click the object and change the visable label to say "22". So the round rectangle now appears to be labeled as 22. The answer you provided is perfect, except it sets the cell to equal the Name Box value (Rounded Rectangle 54). I'm sorry I was not able to fully describe what I would like to get copied into the cell.